# Current status of dbslayer?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dbslayer

Just that I've been researching for SQL solution for NodeJS and MySQL, and saw a lot of good things about dbslayer. But it's been more than 4 days that I couldn't connect to both code.nytimes.com and www.dbslayer.org, hence neither could I install and try dbslayer, whereas I saw cherokee included dbslayer in itself. So I'm wondering if anybody know the current status of dbslayer development? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to use that when there's native MySQL drivers for NodeJS now?

Comment: I actually haven't made decision yet while I'm also aware of db-mysql

Comment: You've got a [ton of options](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=mysql) for connecting today. This project was important in the day, but has long since been supplanted by other, better solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Github repository seems to be [this one](https://github.com/derekg/dbslayer), what is indicated by [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/derekg/status/7539410383933440) and the [referenced tumlbr post](http://derekg.org/post/1672582722/dbslayer-moved-to-github). This also indicates that [Derek Gottfrid](https://twitter.com/derekg) was the main responsible person for the project, who posted on Twitter [last time in october 2012 about this project](https://twitter.com/derekg/status/256725988690513922).

Since the last changes [at Github are multiple years old](https://github.com/derekg/dbslayer/graphs/contributors) and there are [practically no Tweets](https://twitter.com/search?q=dbslayer&src=typd&f=realtime) about this on Twitter anymore, I would call this project dead.